# Row with schema add extra quote compare to Row from the pipeline so that the PAssert fails

Tags: java, row, pipeline, apache-beam, assertion

my unit tests failed for a wired reason

the **SimpleFunction<PubsubMessage, KV<String, Row>>** got **PubsubMessage** and returns a pipeline containing **PCollection<KV<String, Row>>**.

I took only the value from **KV** by: pipeline.apply(Values.create()) so that the metadata contains just the Row.

but when I create an equivalent Row, somehow it's created with an extra quote so that the assertion failed

The code from the test:

```
Row value = Row.withSchema(XXX.valueSchema())
  ...
 .withFieldValue("Template", ((JSONObject)json.get("template")).get("value").toString())
 .build();
```

The code from the function:

```
KV<String, Row> result = FUNC({
    ...
    Row item = Row.withSchema(XXX.valueSchema())
        ...
        .withFieldValue("Template", message.template.get("value").toString())
        .build();
        
    return KV<"key", item>;
});

Row metadata = result.apply(Values.create())
```

The Rows content is almost the same except that the template field from the Row in the pipeline came up without a quote while the one that I created was built with an extra quote so that the assertion fails

```
PAssert.thatSingleton(metadata).isEqualTo(value);
```

Screenshots:
[image: compare in InteliJ unified]

[image: compare in InteliJ side by side]